# How to drop QuickFix tag if i can't reach message with this tag

Tags: c#, quickfix, quickfixn

I'm sending OrderNewSingle message and server returns message with tag 18=u and i want to drop this tag , but i can't catch this message in fromApp and fromAdmin functions.
Its ExecutionReport message _ 35=8.In this message  tag:18=u and "u" value was add in FIX5.0SP2 and i'm using Fix4.4 , i think before message will reach function it's rejected and i want to somewhere drop 18 tag or ignore.

Comment: in which message did you receive this kind of tag?

Comment: its ExecutionReport message - 35=8. I'm new in QuickFix, 18=u value was add FIX5.0SP2 and i'm using Fix4.4 , i think before message will reach function it's rejected before and i want to somewhere drop 18 tag or ignore.

Comment: You must use FIX5.0 SP2 in order to handle properly this kind of tag. Please upgrade you engine

Comment: @stexcec there is no way to drop or ignore it ?

Comment: Maybe, but I never tried before, you can use a custom dictionary

Comment: is it possible to set as main dictionary Fix4.4 and if it's not work use fix5.0SP2 ?

Comment: The solution is add value ‘u’ into FIX44.xml inside tag 18. It works for me .

Comment: great! good job

Comment: Yep, that's the right thing to do.  Your DD xml file should always be modified to match your counterparty's specification.  That's QuickFIX 101.